# Customize DataTables pagination fror ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pagination

Hi have an api made with Laravel. This api will return the paginatted records of data. So it will include the data, count, total, hasMorePages and currentPage. I am retur

[image]

How do I customize the pagination links in the DataTable? Also, I want to put a callback ajax function to fetch the next page. I checked the documentation `https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide`

But I cannot find what I need to match my requirements. Here's my javascript:

```
$("#search_games").click(function(){
var from = $("#from_date").val();
var to = $("#to_date").val();
console.log(from);
console.log(to);

$.post("/api/v1/get_games_result", { from: from, to: to }, function (data) {
    if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) {
        var t = $('#example').DataTable();
        t.clear().draw();
        var count = data.count;
        var currentPage = data.currentPage;
        var hasMorePages = data.hasMorePages;
        var total = data.total;
        var records = data.data;
        console.log(records.length);

        $.each(records, function (key, value) {
            var game_data = value.game_data;

            t.row.add( [
                game_data.game_id,
                game_data.game_date+" "+game_data.game_time,
                game_data.game_closing
            ] ).draw( false );

        });
    }
    var info = t.page.info();
    console.log(data);
});
```

});

I want to make a function that when user clicked the pagination page button, I will request for the next page:

[image]

Comment: I hope you have looked at datatables server-side processing example. I guess that should help you may be. I don't know Laravel, but the example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) is in PHP which should suffice.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal Thanks. I've look at it but the example is very different from my api return

Comment: So I assume you do not require any search or sort functionality? Because if you implement your own API, the searching and sorting will not function correctly. Since it will only search and sort the data displayed in your table and not fetch from server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you get the ID of Next link.
[image]

Then add the click event in the IF clause:

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) {
    <....>
    $('#ID of Next link').click(function() {
      Repost JSON Code here;
    });
}
```